# #NeedHelp flutter not worked on my machine

Tags: android, flutter, dart, development-environment

[Flutter Doesn't worked on My Machine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZVTm.png)

I'm Using win 11 and I want set flutter in my machine and I set that's path on system and user both variables also. and try many of time after restart but it's not work. what should I do? Please Help...

Answer (score 0):

Move your flutter folder to main c directory out of all folder and also update the path and don't forget to add flutter and dart plugin/extensions and try i think it will be fix.

Answer (score 0):

While Installing flutter keep these instructions in mind:

1. Download flutter SDK correctly from here
   https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows

> Don't Forget to install Android Studio because Flutter needs it to build android apps.

2. After downloading, Extract the SDK in the C directory.
3. Then open the flutter SDK folder, Go to the "bin" folder, Copy this folder path, and set this path in environment variables.
4. Open your Code Editor (Android Studio OR VSCode) and go to extensions. Do install Flutter and Dart extensions. Install both of them.
5. Now open your terminal/cmd and run the "flutter doctor" command to check the status. You will see the missing things which you need to install. After installing these requirements you are good to go.

[image]